# In R, I want to plot all of data frame's columns (but last one) against its last columns using ggplop in a for loop. It doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame and I want to plot all of its columns but the last one against its last columns using ggplot. Thereafter I use a for loop and grid.arrange to have a row of 13 plots. But the output is just repeating one plot all over the row.
that is, just plot the 13th column (last iteration) against the 14th column.

```
times1<-times[timeindex] ### this is a vector

mat_ind    <- matrix(0, nrow=120,ncol=13) 



mat_ind [,1] <- logBF_Apollo_1[,1]  ### all logBF_Apollo_1,..., logBF_Apollo_1 are matrices

mat_ind [,2] <- logBF_Apollo_2[,1]

mat_ind [,3] <- logBF_Apollo_3[,1]

mat_ind [,4] <- logBF_Apollo_4[,1]

mat_ind [,5] <- logBF_Apollo_5[,1]

mat_ind [,6] <- logBF_Apollo_6[,1]

mat_ind [,7] <- logBF_Apollo_7[,1]

mat_ind [,8] <- logBF_Apollo_8[,1]

mat_ind [,9] <- logBF_Apollo_9[,1]

mat_ind [,10] <- logBF_Apollo_10[,1]

mat_ind [,11] <- logBF_Apollo_11[,1]

mat_ind [,12] <- logBF_Apollo_12[,1]

mat_ind [,13] <- logBF_Apollo_13[,1]


mat_ind<- data.frame(mat_ind,times1)

library(ggplot2)

library(gridExtra)



for(i  in 1:13 ){
  p[[i]] <-ggplot(mat_ind, aes(x = times1, y = mat_ind[,i])) +
  geom_line() +ylab("") +coord_flip() +
  xlab("")}


figure1 <- grid.arrange(p[[1]],p[[2]],p[[3]],p[[4]],p[[5]],p[[6]],p[[7]],p[[8]],p[[9]],
                   p[[10]],p[[11]],p[[12]],p[[13]], ncol = 13, nrow =1)


figure
```

The results just repeat the last iteration of the for loop.
that is the problem is that the output of for loop is:

p[[1]]=p[[2]]=...=p[[13]] ### this a problem.

Could you please let me know how I can fix it?

Comment: This is alomost certainly a "`ggplot` evaluates lazily" problem>  When the `for` loop ends and`ggplot` eventually evaulates, all the calls use the same (final) value of the index variable.  The simplest solution is to convert the `for` loop to `lapply` or similar.  This will force evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Limey's comment is probably the reason for your frustrations and his solution would work too. So I'm not going to focus on solving your problem, but rather I'd like to propose to use `facet_wrap()` instead of arranging all the plots with `grid.arrange()`, based on the impression that all your plots have similar structure anyway.

I'm assuming you got a set of variables that are similarly named, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

times <- 1:120

logBF_Apollo_1 <- matrix(rnorm(prod(120, 2)), nrow = 120)
logBF_Apollo_2 <- matrix(rnorm(prod(120, 2)), nrow = 120)
logBF_Apollo_3 <- matrix(rnorm(prod(120, 2)), nrow = 120)
logBF_Apollo_4 <- matrix(rnorm(prod(120, 2)), nrow = 120)
logBF_Apollo_5 <- matrix(rnorm(prod(120, 2)), nrow = 120)
# To lazy to type the rest
```

Instead of manually copying the first column of each of those into a new matrix, we can program on the language to get a list of the first columns, which we can then arrange as a matrix.

```r
first_columns <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
  sym <- as.symbol(paste0("logBF_Apollo_", i))
  eval(sym)[, 1]
})
mat_ind <- do.call(cbind, first_columns)
```

What we'll do next is to format the names a bit, add the `times` column and convert the data from a wide format to a long format.

```
colnames(mat_ind) <- paste0("pretty_name_", seq_len(ncol(mat_ind)))
mat_ind <- data.frame(mat_ind, times)
df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(mat_ind, dplyr::starts_with("pretty_name"))
```

It then becomes pretty easy to generate 1 plot containing all panels.

```
ggplot(df, aes(times, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ name, ncol = ncol(mat_ind) - 1) # -1 because of the times-column
```

[image]